# mysql update with data from another table with join on two fields

Tags: mysql

I need to update 1 table with data from another where two fields match. I have a query but it's just locking up.

I have an employees_training_courses table
I have a company_training_categories table

I need to get the ID from company_training_categories where both the name and the account_id are the same in both tables.

So far I have this...

```
update employee_training_courses tc join company_training_categories ctc on ctc.name = tc.name AND ctc.account_id = tc.account_id set tc.company_training_category_id = ctc.id;
```

i can leave the query running, but it's clearly getting hung up somewhere !

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
update employee_training_courses tc join
       company_training_categories ctc
       on ctc.name = tc.name AND ctc.account_id = tc.account_id
    set tc.company_training_category_id = ctc.id;
```

This is a very reasonable query.  You probably just need indexes to speed it up.  I would recommend:

```
create index idx_company_training_categories_2 on company_training_categories(name, account_id)
```

or even:

```
create index idx_company_training_categories_3 on company_training_categories(name, account_id, id)
```